# Issue porting Jenkinsfile scripted to declarative withEnv{} => environment{}

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, environment, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have issue porting scripted to declarative pipeline. I used to have in scripted:
//Scripted

```
def myEnv = [:]

stage ('Prepare my env') { [...] myEnv = ... }

stage ('Fancy stuff') {
    node() {
        withEnv(myEnv) {
        // here use what is defined in myEnv
        }
    }    
     stage ('Fancy stuff2') {
    node() {
        withEnv(myEnv) {
        // here use what is defined in myEnv
        } }    

}
```

and now in declarative I would like to have

//Declarative

```
def myEnv = [:]
 pipeline {

agent none

stage('Prepare my env') {
    steps {
        script {
            [...]
            myEnv = ...
        }
    }
}

stages {
    environment { myEnv }
    stage('Fancy stuff') {
        [...]
    }
    stage('Fancy stuff2') {
        [...]
    }
} }
```

when I try to run this, it fails withEnv

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: WorkflowScript: xx: "myEnv" is not a valid environment
>   expression. Use "key = value" pairs with valid Java/shell keys.

Fair enough. 
What should I do to be able to use declarative environment { } to avoid using withEnv(myEnv) one in every further steps?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the part you are missing is the usage of `environment` clause.

Instead of

```
environment { myEnv }
```

It should be

```
environment { myEnvVal = myEnv }
```

Just as the error method mentions this should be key = value pair.

Comment: Well in my scripted pipeline, def myEnv = [:] is a map with several values not a single one. I would have no issue with a single environment but I have several of them.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder Why would you be using a Groovy map as an environment variable though? That sounds a lot like it should be a parameter instead.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard The environment consist of dozens of variables that comprise information about target to deploy, port to use, DB to use, paths,... and so on. The parameters of the job relates more to the stages to run or branch of lib to use and base for the environment.

Comment: Then you can join those values with a separator in `environment` assign them to a key, and deserialize them before use. `environment` doesn't provide you with a way to set it with a map.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the type of your variable `myEnv`. You define it as a map when you do `def myEnv = [:]`.

So it works with `withEnv` that [takes a map as parameter](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) but it does not work with `environment {...}` that [takes only "key = value" statements](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment).

The solution depends on how you add environment variables contained in `myEnv`.

The simplest way is using `environment` directive by listing all the key/values contained in your former variable `myEnv`:

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    environment {
        test1 = 'test-1'
        test2 = 'test-2'
    }
    stages{
        stage('Fancy stuff'){
            steps{
                echo "${test1}"
            }
        }
        stage('Fancy stuff2'){
            steps{
                echo "${test2}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you also do it the *scripted way* :

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        stage('Prepare my env') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def test = []
                    for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
                        test[i] = 'test-' + i.toString()
                    }
                    test1 = test[1]
                    test2 = test[2]
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Fancy stuff'){
            steps{
                echo "${test1}"
            }
        }
        stage('Fancy stuff2'){
            steps{
                echo "${test2}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that test1 and test2 are written in the Jenkinsfile. In my case, the variables are dynamically built and can even be added when starting a job.

Comment: With the _scripted way_ you can do the same thing you do in your former stage `Prepare my env`. But instead of adding you key/values in the variable `myEnv`, you declare it directly in the script.